# Verify bcrypt hash from Adonis in Laravel

Tags: laravel, bcrypt, adonis.js

Hey having a little trouble making password hashes made in Adonis work in Laravel an example is

```
// Adonis
> await Hash.make('password')
'$bcrypt$v=98$r=10$cIF1Ev2ATA6/iYv4kddXCQ$qcrDoGjsiB2eLq1/vCZWiAZ8bEs4+Qs'

// Laravel
>>> Hash::make('password')
=> "$2y$10$kV7kssmFuFOydBewIp9ele8GMkWGDPpte6jGGDAabpsBmxtzWxfZW"
```

So looking the hashes they both seem to use 10 rounds. The Adonis splits the salt and hash with a $

So I thought just extracting the salt + hash and formatting in Laravels format. Then checking it in Laravel example

```
// Laravel
Hash::check('password', '$2y$10$cIF1Ev2ATA6/iYv4kddXCQqcrDoGjsiB2eLq1/vCZWiAZ8bEs4+Qs');
```

However its coming back false for no match.

Not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hash is in the [PHC string format](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md):

```
$bcrypt$v=98$r=10$cIF1Ev2ATA6/iYv4kddXCQ$qcrDoGjsiB2eLq1/vCZWiAZ8bEs4+Qs
```

This format uses the standard base64 alphabet for encoding bytes in base64:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
```

The second hash is in [Modular Crypt Format](https://github.com/ademarre/binary-mcf):

```
$2y$10$kV7kssmFuFOydBewIp9ele8GMkWGDPpte6jGGDAabpsBmxtzWxfZW
```

This format does not use the standard Base64 alphabet, it instead uses Unix Crypt alphabet:

```
./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

You need to decode the bytes using the typical Base64 alphabet, and then re-encode them using the Crypt alphabet, or find an implementation of BCrypt for Laravel that accepts the PHC format.

Comment: Hey thanks, this looks correct! I just can't find a function for encoding the bytes back into Unix Crypt alphabet in PHP.

Comment: I can't really help with that in PHP, but I can point you at a Go implementation: https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/crypto/+/e495a2d5:bcrypt/base64.go;l=13;drc=089bfa5675191fd96a44247682f76ebca03d7916;bpv=1;bpt=1, and the base64 implementation that accepts an arbitrary alphabet: https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/crypto/+/e495a2d5:bcrypt/base64.go;l=13;drc=089bfa5675191fd96a44247682f76ebca03d7916;bpv=1;bpt=1